# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in django

Tags: django

I want to generate some random information with faker. but when i execute the populating file an error showing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'practice'. here is my directory and code. I am beginner in python.[project folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaNM.jpg)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'first_app'
```

]

```
`import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'practice.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecords,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['search','social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def pupulate(N=5):
    for entry in range (N):
        top = add_topic()
        
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()
        
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topics=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]
        acc_reg = AccessRecords.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print ("populating script")
        pupulate(20)
        print('populating complete')`
```

Comment: try to put your faker file in your main `PRACTICE` directory

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that you should also add `practice` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Now it's not showing any error but database is not seeding.